# How to change the Write Ahead Log directory

Tags: postgresql, write-ahead-logging

How do you change the defined WAL directory?
During the installation I defined a directory, `/var/lib/wal` and the `$PGDATA/pg_xlog` has a symbolic link pointing to that directory.

How do I change the postgres setting to write the WAL files elsewhere - without having to re-install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done according to the documentation [here]:(http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/wal-internals.html)

> It is advantageous if the log is located on a different disk from the
>   main database files. This can be achieved by moving the pg_xlog
>   directory to another location (while the server is shut down, of
>   course) and creating a symbolic link from the original location in the
>   main data directory to the new location.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I was hoping to achieve this by changing a parameter in postgresql.conf .

Comment: Fraid not :-( - it's quite an operation to change the WAL directory - if you think about it, it's easy to see why. With buffering, you never know if there are any transactions in limbo hanging around before changing your WAL location - changing on a live system could leave your system in an inconsistent state. Maybe a feature request (change WAL without bouncing the server)? I don't see why it couldn't be possible if they wished to - I mean hot backups are possible, so why not a hot WAL location change? I'd say it's more a question of a (competent dev) sitting down than a theoretical no-no.

Comment: Aye! A log switch or a simple rsync could probably do the job.

Comment: I came here after reading the documentation, because not sure how do the moving. Maybe is obvious but still don't see it.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know it's recommended, just was googling if this even legal to do so. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

It is very-very simple:

1. Make sure your postgres is not running!
2. mount your WAL disk to an easy accessible folder
3. check the permissions of your WAL directory ($PG_DATA/pg_xlog/)
4. copy or move all files from $PG_DATA/pg_xlog/ into this directory
5. unmount the WAL disk and remount it to $PG_DATA/pg_xlog/
6. Check the permissions and fix if necessary (of the directory and files inside)
7. Start postgres again ^^

You are done!

Comment: Seems like the folder is called pg_wal now, not pg_xlog. Please check your data directory and configuration files!